# Remove 'duplicate' objects from array by comparing sub properties (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I receive an array of complex objects from the server. I would like to filter the original array to get a new array with unique objects by a sub-property of an each object, i.e :

```
let arr1 = originalArray;
let arr2 = originalArray.filter((ele, idx, arr) => ....
```

Now for example, arr1 consists of 3 objects:

```
firstObj = {
    id: 0,
    Details:
        {
            License: 123456
        },
    name: 'abc'
};
secondObj = {
    id: 1,
    Details:
        {
            License: 131313
        },
    name: 'xcd'
};
thirdObj = {
    id: 2,
    Details:
        {
            License: 123456
        },
    name: 'bcd'
};
```

So, I want to filter the array so that the newly returned array will consist of only two objects where the 'License' property will be unique, that is, one of the objects with the same 'License' will be removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `array.reduce` to loop through source array and add items to result if it does not contain same `Details.License`

```
let result = [firstObj, secondObj, thirdObj].reduce((arr, item) => {
    let exists = !!arr.find(x => x.Details.License === item.Details.License);
    if(!exists){
        arr.push(item);
    }
    return arr;
}, []);
```

Comment: Awsome solution :)

Answer (score 4):

If order they occur is not important can pass them into a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) using `Licence` values as keys.

Map keys must be unique so this will overwrite duplicates as they occur while creating the Map and return last instance of each duplicate

```js
let uniques = [...new Map(data.map(o=>[o.Details.License,o])).values()];


console.log(uniques)
```

```html
<script>
let data = [{
  id: 0,
  Details: {
    License: 123456
  },
  name: 'abc'
}, {
  id: 1,
  Details: {
    License: 131313
  },
  name: 'xcd'
}, {
  id: 2,
  Details: {
    License: 123456
  },
  name: 'bcd'
}]
</script>
```

---

Alternate  approach using `Array#filter` and a `Set` to track unique values

```js
let licSet = new Set();
let uniques = data.filter(({Details: o}) => !licSet.has(o.License) && licSet.add(o.License));


console.log(uniques)
```

```html
<script>
  let data = [{
    id: 0,
    Details: {
      License: 123456
    },
    name: 'abc'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    Details: {
      License: 131313
    },
    name: 'xcd'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    Details: {
      License: 123456
    },
    name: 'bcd'
  }]
</script>
```

Comment: Also a great solution, thanks. I should get more accustomed to using the spread operator.

Comment: If large data set I believe this would be more performant than using nested `find()`